# Why is supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange() spontaneously trigging after about 10 minutes

Tags: authentication, next.js, supabase

I'm using Next.js with a Supabase DB, and Supabase magic links for auth. I have the following effect in my `_app.tsx` file:

```
useEffect(() => {
        const {data: authListener} = supabase.auth.onAuthStateChange((event, session) => {
            handleAuthChange(event, session)
            if (event === 'SIGNED_IN') {
                setIsAuthenticated(true)
                console.log('SIGNED_IN')
                console.log(`router.asPath: ${router.asPath}`)
                if(router.asPath.includes('/signin')) {
                    console.log('redirect from signin')
                    router.push('/')
                }
            }
            if (event === 'SIGNED_OUT') {
                setIsAuthenticated(false)
                console.log('SIGNED_OUT')
                router.push('/signin')
            }
        })
        checkUser()
        return () => {
            authListener.unsubscribe()
        }
    }, [])
```

About 10 minutes after I log in, this effect spontaneously fires causing me to redirect to the home page. Based on the console logs I have added to the effect, I can see that the event is `'SIGNED_IN'` and `router.asPath` looks like this:

```
/signin#access_token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJhdWQiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIiwiZXhwIjoxNjY0ODkzODgxLCJzdWIiOiJjY2I3MTEzYS1iZjY2LTQzMzAtODg2OC1mNjZhMjIxMTYyMTYiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im5laWxnaXJhcmRpQHBtLm1lIiwicGhvbmUiOiIiLCJhcHBfbWV0YWRhdGEiOnsicHJvdmlkZXIiOiJlbWFpbCIsInByb3ZpZGVycyI6WyJlbWFpbCJdfSwidXNlcl9tZXRhZGF0YSI6e30sInJvbGUiOiJhdXRoZW50aWNhdGVkIiwic2Vzc2lvbl9pZCI6IjI3MDFlY2EzLWRhZjYtNDhiNi04YzQ1LTdhODBjMDM1OTIxYiJ9.9ma0xFfqrJIvv-ryDhjcJCgd8XiCGP6SEf39ZFUzhq8&expires_in=3600&refresh_token=Zt0xjMuX-W8E7nBRYuUAlw&token_type=bearer&type=magiclink
```

Why am I spontaneously being logged in again when I am already logged in?

Comment: Have you tried to increase the JWT interval ( & reuse interval) here:
https://app.supabase.com/project/_/auth/settings

Comment: @Mansueli `JWT expiry limit` is set to the default of `3600` (one hour) and `Reuse Interval` is set to `10` seconds. Reuse Interval is described in the settings as "Time interval where the same refresh token can be used to request for an access token." I'm not very familiar with JWT workflows so I'm not really clear on what that means. Should I try increasing that value?

Comment: Currently, Supabase fires the `SIGNED_IN` even when a token is just refreshed - see https://github.com/supabase/gotrue-js/issues/224. My guess is that you are getting the `SIGNED_IN` event because the token is refreshed. However, I am not sure why you are getting it in 10min instead of 60min (it should match the JWT expiry timeout). Maybe you can also listen for the `TOKEN_REFRESHED` event just to confirm that this is the case and if it is - you can use the workaround I have described in the reference issue.

Comment: @chipilov Thank you for that information. I ended up implementing the magic link auth using NextAuth. If for some reason I need to go back to using Supabase for auth I will heed this advice. Cheers.